# Difference between system.gc() and runtime.gc()

Tags: java, android, garbage-collection

What is the difference between `System.gc()` and `Runtime.gc()`?

Comment: you should learn to look at the javadocs first.  And if the Android javadocs don't answer your questions go to the Sun / Oracle javadocs next.  (Yea, I know the code is different, but as a general rule the behaviour is the same ...)

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Both are same. `System.gc()` is effectively equivalent to `Runtime.gc()`. `System.gc()`internally calls `Runtime.gc()`.

The only difference is `System.gc()` is a class method where as `Runtime.gc()` is an instance method. So, `System.gc()` is more convenient.

Comment: but what is the purpose of creating two same method with same functionality

Comment: `Runtime.gc()` cannot be invoked directly. 
`gc()` is an instance method and to properly invoke the Garbage Collector, you need to invoke the static method `getRuntime()` to eventually invoke the `gc()` method. Hence, you need to do:
`Runtime.getRuntime().gc()`.

Answer (score 22):

From looking at the source code: `System.gc()` is implemented as

```
Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
```

So it's just a convenience method.

Comment: No longer true, at least with API 23. There is a flag which might prevent Runtimg.getRuntime().gc() from being run if you call System.gc()

Answer (score 9):

[See the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#gc--)

`System.gc()` is equivalent to `Runtime.getRuntime().gc()`

Comment: Please link to an updated version of the docs. 1.4.2 is really old.

Comment: Sorry, was just using the first thing Google gave me. Which really reflects badly on the OP -- this is a question Google can answer.

Comment: Thanks for fixing it. I would say that it reflects badly on Google. Why are outdated docs the top search results? Can't Google rank the new docs higher than the old ones?

Comment: AFAIK Google ranks pages mostly by hits, and older docs are going to rank higher because they've been around longer. Also: it did rank the latest highest when I searched for "java lang System" the first one was from searching "System.gc()". So it sometimes does it.

Comment: I've been seeing this with Google search results for java APIs for years. You can rationalize the behavior all you want. The desired behavior is to show current docs at the top of the list. Showing old docs first is broken and it would be nice if Google fixed it already. It's been years.

Answer (score 2):

`Runtime.gc()` is a native method where as `System.gc()` is non - native method which in turn calls the `Runtime.gc()`

Answer (score 2):

**System.gc():**

1: It is a class method(static method).

2: Non-Native method.(Code which doesn't directly interacts with Hardware and System Resources).

3: System.gc(), Internally calls Runtime.getRuntime().gc().

**Runtime.gc():**

1: Instance method.

2: Native method(A programming language which directly interacts with Hardware and System Resources.).

Answer (score 1):

Both are same **System.gc()** is effectively equivalent to **Runtime.gc()**

*System.gc()* internally calls *Runtime.gc()*.

The only difference is :

*System.gc()* is a class (static) method where as *Runtime.gc()* is an instance method. So, *System.gc()* is more convenient.

**System.gc()**

```
public final class System extends Object{

    public static void gc(){
        .
        .
         Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
    
    }
    .
    .

}
```

**Runtime.gc()**

```
public class Runtime extends Object{

    public void gc(){

        // ...

    }
    .
    .
    .

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the runtime system the gc is instance method but in system method the gc is static .

because of this reason we prefer to use system.gc().

Comment: Doesn't answer the question.